# accessing all document fields in a collection but only wants to read specific fields

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I want to know how to use `.doc()` in a `onSnapshot` since I do want to get a real time update changes on my firestore database. [Here is the visual of my firestore database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCI1v.png)

I do have this `Availability` collection and I do want to access all of its fields and it is auto-generated id with an array of fields of `available` and `busy`. Now I want to only wants to access `available` and `busy` on at a time in a query.

I have tried reading the the article in firebase [where I can liste to multiple documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection).

However the documents only specific, I want all documents to be read and wants to specific in an array field on what to display.

```
import { collection, query, where, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

const q = query(collection(db, "cities"), where("state", "==", "CA"));
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
  const cities = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      cities.push(doc.data().name);
  });
  console.log("Current cities in CA: ", cities.join(", "));
});
```